# Is it possible to get CPU usage of last 5 minutes of any process?

Tags: python, psutil

Now, I can get current CPU usage of a process using `psutil`, but I want to get average of CPU usage of last 5, 10 and 15 minutes.

Comment: Just keep track over 5, 10, 15 minutes and take an average?

Comment: I'm doing same now, but I want previous 5 minute's record. Is it possible ?

Comment: I'd just keep track continually and take the last *n* minutes on record for averaging.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion 1**:

I haven't tested the following code - only sharing it for illustration sake.

Use 3 thread each calculating/printing 5, 10 , 15 mins CPU usage. 
Use [`psutil.cpu_percent(interval=0.0)`](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.cpu_percent), as per docs:

> Return a float representing the current system-wide CPU utilization as
>   a percentage… When interval is 0.0 or None compares system CPU times
>   elapsed since last call or module import, returning immediately…

after the psutil.cpu_percent(interval=0.0), put the thread to sleep for the specific interval (the time you want average usage):

```
import os
import time 
import psutil

.......

p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())  # pid of the current process
p.cpu_percent(interval=0.0)
time.sleep(300)  # for 5 mins cpu usage  

......
```

---

**Suggestion 2**:

A single thread recording (appending to an array) cpu usage at a fixed interval (every minute), another thread taking the values and calculating the averages i.e. gets last five values and divide by 5, similarly last 10 values and divide by 10.

For this case, the first thread must be putting values to a queue with a fixed length i.e. 15 (last 15 minutes cpu usages). For this you can use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
q = collections.deque(maxlen=15)
q.append(elem)
```

> If maxlen is not specified or is None, deques may grow to an arbitrary
>   length. Otherwise, the **deque is bounded to the specified maximum
>   length. Once a bounded length deque is full, when new items are added,
>   a corresponding number of items are discarded from the opposite end**.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to just get it magically, without logging it during the specified time duration. Here is a example on how to do that:

```
import psutil, statistics

process_to_benchmark = 'MyProcessName' # name: str
seconds_to_benchmark = 300 # seconds: int

avg_load = []
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if process_to_benchmark in proc.name():
        print(f'Benchmarking "{proc.name()}" for {seconds_to_benchmark} seconds ...')
        for __ in range(seconds_to_benchmark):
            avg_load.append(psutil.cpu_percent(interval=3))

print(f'Process used {round(statistics.mean(avg_load), 2)}% CPU Load on average')
```